# How to relaunch a application immediately in android after being killed?

Tags: java, android

Hi i make an antivirus and anti theft application on android. I want to relaunch my application immediately after being killed by a task killer. For now, i only use `START_STICKY` method from service, but it takes a few time to restart my application and service after being killed. My antivirus and anti theft application should be launch immediately because if the owner's mobile phone was lost, an owner still can monitoring where the last location of their mobile phone. Has anyone know how to restart an application on android immediately which is better than `START_STICKY` method? like a Lookout mobile security?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you could do is use a service activity, this cannot be killed by task killers if I remember this right :)!

A service is made by making a simple extension like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
```

And you can start this with this:

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

And stop this with

```
stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

Comment: Think this is only true as of Android 2.3?

Comment: I think its only possible if a phone has root access, else killing services is not a option. I think it is since an earlier version of android, you have to look this up :)

Comment: @Kurru: is it possible to use this on android 2.2??

Comment: @Wesso: my problem is like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796589/how-do-some-app-make-their-service-running-relaunching-it-even-after-killed-c?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: You will have to test it, if people really want to kill an application it will be always possible. A small example of a service is in my edited awnser.

Comment: @Wesso: thanks for your answer.. yes.. i use the service same with you.. i use START_STICKY for relaunching that service if the task killer killed it. but it takes a few time while restarting (about 20 seconds) and my application should wake all time for user's security.. (the example lookout mobile security and widget locker. that application can't be killed from task killer) any idea to do that?? thanks.